# How can I change the name of another Excel workbook I'm referencing in my code by entering the file name into a cell?

Tags: vba, excel

**Here's what I'm trying to do.**

My Excel workbook, InspectionFormTemplate3.4.xlsm, exists as a template to copy over data from various other workbooks that have a totally different format. The code works for copying the data over, but I have 1500 reports to convert and every time I have to manually go into my code and ctrl+f replace all instances it references the report to be converted. Instead, I enter data into a cell (S50) and tried replacing the referenced file name with a variable I named oldfilename. That is what gives me an error, and that's what I'm stuck on.

I've looked around for hours in order to find something that does what I'm trying to do, but I have no real experience with VBA at all. I think this is probably just a simple syntax error.

**So, here's what I tried so far with my current code.**

```
Private Sub ConvertButton_Click()
```

`Dim oldfilename As String`

```
oldfilename = Range("S50")
```

'Name of bldg and date

```
Workbooks("InspectionFormTemplate2018.3.4.xlsm").Worksheets("COVER PAGE").Range("C9").Value = Workbooks("ReporttoConvert.xls").Worksheets("Cover Page").Range("B5").Value
```

Obviously here, "ReporttoConvert" is a placeholder for an actual workbook name. It works when I manually insert file names, but I need it to look more like this instead:

```
Workbooks("oldfilename")
```

in order for it to change to whatever I input as the file name in cell S50. I'm sure this is probably pretty simple, but I have no clue what this would be called or how to do it.

Comment: If `oldfilename` is the variable you use to store the name of the opened workbook you want to work with, then `Workbooks(oldfilename)` (notice there are not double quotes) should work for you.

Comment: I forgot to mention this somehow (sorry!) but I tried many combinations of that sort. It didn't work when I did that. It'd still spit out an error regardless.

Comment: If you don't tell which error you get ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, your macro enabled workbook should be saved in the same folder as the other workbooks, else you will have to change 'ThisWorkbook.path...

```
Dim OpenWb As String
OpenWb = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("COVER PAGE").Range("S50").Value

Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & OpenWb

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("COVER PAGE").Range("C9").Value = Workbooks(OpenWb).Worksheets("Cover Page").Range("B5").Value
```

Comment: It would probably be tidier to assign the newly opened workbook to an Object - easier to close at the end, and the only time you need to reference the Workbook name would be when you open it

Comment: @chronocidal +1, I agree; but,  i don't like to write the whole code for new individuals, It gives them a chance to learn, or ask another question.

Comment: Thank you very much! After some fiddling, I got this to work. I had another idea: would it be possible to make this iterate through all .xls files in a directory and save these as separate files instead of reopening the template each time?

Comment: That would be a good question; I would suggest you do a search in SO for "loop through all files in folder" and try to write some code when/if you have a problem ask another question in SO